# c++ mutex cout not printing everything

Tags: c++, mutex

I'm creating a thread managing class, to which i can post tasks (functions + parameters), and the class will take care of threading them.

the problem is not so much related to this whole class (i think), but more a general problem with locking shared resources when use multiple threads.
here is the code:

main test file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include "Ttask_1.h"
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

bool quit=false;

void* square(void* n);
void* print(void* n);
mutex cout_mutex;
mutex res_mutex;

bool cout_locked=false;

vector<Ttask_1<void*,void*>*> tasks1;
vector<Ttask_1<void*,void*>*> tasks2;

void check_for_work(vector<void*> &vec,vector<Ttask_1<void*,void*>*> &tasks)
{
    while(!quit)
    {
        if(tasks.size()!=0)
        {
            (*tasks[0]).run(vec);
            tasks.erase(tasks.begin());
        }
        else
            quit=true;
    }
    while(cout_locked){}
    cout_locked=true;
    cout<<"thread done"<<endl;
    cout_locked=false;

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<void*> vec;
    int n=5;
    //int *n_p=&n;
    //Ttask_1<void*,void*> task(&n,square);
    tasks1.push_back(new Ttask_1<void*,void*>(&n,square,true));
    tasks1.push_back(new Ttask_1<void*,void*>(&n,print,false));

    tasks2.push_back(new Ttask_1<void*,void*>(&n,square,true));
    tasks2.push_back(new Ttask_1<void*,void*>(&n,print,false));



    thread Thread1(check_for_work,ref(vec),ref(tasks2));


    thread Thread2(check_for_work,ref(vec),ref(tasks1));
    //(&Ttask_1<int,int>::run,&task,ref(vec));
   // task.run(vec,Thread);
    Thread1.join();
    Thread2.join();


    int a;
    cin>>a;
    return 0;
}

void* print(void* n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<*(int*)(n);i++)
    {
        while(cout_locked){}
        cout_locked=true;
        cout<<i<<endl;
        cout_locked=false;
    }
    void* a;
    return a;
}

void* square(void* n)
{

    int res=(*(int*)n)*(*(int*)n);

    while(cout_locked){}
    cout_locked=true;
    cout<<res<<endl;
    cout_locked=false;

    int *res_p=new int;
    res_p=&res;
    return res_p;
}
```

the ttask_1 class:

```
#ifndef task_Test_Ttask_1_h
#define task_Test_Ttask_1_h
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

extern mutex res_mutex;

template <class type1, class ret>
class Ttask_1
{
public:
    Ttask_1(type1 arg_in,ret(*func_p_in)(type1),bool result)
    {
        safe_result=result;
        arg1=arg_in;
        func_p=func_p_in;
    }
    void run(vector<void*> &res_vector)
    {

        ret res=(*func_p)(arg1);

        if(safe_result)
        {
            void *res_p=&res;
            res_mutex.lock();
            res_vector.push_back(res_p);
            res_mutex.unlock();
        }
        done=true;

    }
    bool is_done(){return done;}
private:
    bool safe_result;
    bool done=false;
    type1 arg1;
    ret(*func_p)(type1);
};

#endif
```

as you can see, i implemented my own 'locking' thing on the cout, after i saw the mutex wasn't working. the behaviour is exactly the same so this is not the issue.

and that behaviour is as follows:

I expect the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,25 and the string 'thread done' to all be printed twice before the program terminates.

However, very often (not always, but often) i get this output:

> 25 0 1 2 3 4 thread done thread done

so a couple of numbers are missing, and i have no idea what causes this. as i said, eve if i replace my own

```
    while(cout_locked){}
    cout_locked=true;
```

by

```
    cout_mutex.locked();
```

and

```
    cout_locked=false;
```

by

```
    cout_mutex.unlock()
```

nothing changes.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please revert to using the mutex. Your own locking is utterly worthless due to the race conditions in it.

Comment: Yea oke, but like i said, even with the mutex the bevaiour is the same

Comment: too complicated to follow. A smaller demo would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is that `quit` is a global variable. As soon as one thread finishes the other thread won't do any more work (which could include doing no work at all). You'll need a `quit`-style variable for each thread, or just use the `size` check as your while loop's condition.

You also put the address of a local variable into your `vector` within the `run` function, so your results may be unpredictable. Why not have the results vector be actually type-safe?

That said there are many functional and idiomatic issues with your code:

- The `cout_locked` variable only appears to work, there's a race condition there - but I'm not actually sure `cout` needs to be locked at all.
- You're treating everything as `void*` throwing away so much type safety that C++ provides if you just let it.
- You mix in-class initialization with constructor initialization (why not also initialize `done` in the constructor).
- Generally prefer constructor initializer lists to assignment in the constructor body to prevent construct-then-assign performance implications.
- You `erase` from the beginning of a vector which is the least efficient location to erase from a vector. If it's representin a queue either use `queue` or `deque` depending on your needs.
- `print` returns a random pointer. If you need it to return `void*` at least have it consistently return null (`0`).

Comment: aah thanks man that's some really good feedback!You are right, it was the quit variable, such a simple mistake:p thanks a lot.  the void* thing is because thats the only way i'v figured out how to make the task thing being able to accept everything. because when i create the tasks vector i have to fill in the template with something, but yea, the arguments and return values should be able to be anything, so did not know how else to do this.  and the rest i mainly a combination of rusty c++ and putting together a quick test

Comment: Concerning the next to the last point: I wouldn't be so sure that `deque` would be better.  Each time I've actually measured, using vector as a queue turned out to be faster.  (In every case, the queue was never very large, and the objects were cheap to copy.  But that's the case here.)

Comment: @James Kanze Good point, especially for MSVC which uses a really tiny chunk size for `deque`s.

Answer (score 0):

This code is returning a pointer to a local variable. This variable will be out of scope by the time it is accessed. It also leaks memory.

```
int *res_p=new int;
res_p=&res;
return res_p;
```

You need to construct the new `int` with the value, instead of taking the address of the local with `&`.

```
return new int(res_p);
```

*You also need to lock whenever you access your task vector.*